# jQuery fadeIn() and fadeOut() with stop(), how to solve incorrect height?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu with some submenus and want to have a nice effect with jQuery *.fadeIn()* and *.fadeOut()* problem is, if a user do a "hover" effect to fast, then goes back to his menu item, this menu item has a height from 5,6 pixels and can't be opened, how can i reset height after every hover effect? I think problem is in *.stop()* function, but i have no idea how to solve this?

My jQuery code is:

```
$('#main_menu > li').hover(
    function () {
        $('ul', this).stop().fadeIn(300);
    }, 
    function () {
        $('ul', this).stop().fadeOut(300);            
    }
);
```

Comment: i would use a extra class for it instead of fade, to avoid inline styles. but try to add an .removeAttr('style') after the .stop()

Comment: I use now this "$('ul', this).addClass('firstsubmenu');", but how can i set a .fadeIn() or a other nice effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to swap the order to stop() and fadeIn()/fadeOut(), because your second stop() may terminate the first fadeIn() when it is still running.

```
$('#main_menu > li').hover(
    function () {
        $('ul', this).fadeIn(300).stop();
    }, 
    function () {
        $('ul', this).fadeOut(300).stop();            
    }
);
```

It may be easier if you can give out a JSFiddle.